# How to get SUM of a column with number of affected rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**How to get SUM of  a column with number of affected rows**

I am trying to get the sum of a column and I will also like to return the number of affected columns.

Example:

```
orders table

id    customer_id       name      amount
----------------------------------------
1      2                burger    5.00
2      2                pizza     6.00
3      2                grape     1.00
4      1                sandwich  4.00
```

Now I want to SUM the amount column for a particular customer(customer_id) and also return number of items(count rows affected)

I am doing this but it only gets the sum of the amount, I would also like to get number number affected rows (count) from this single query:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a `COUNT` as well:

```sql
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = 2
```

If `amount` is a nullable field and you want to only count `NOT NULL` rows, then do a `COUNT(amount)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = 2
```